# Meteor Get From Collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, insert, meteor

New to Meteor. Have a collection `Players` with this data `Players.insert({name: names[i], score: 1);`

`var names = ["example"];`

I want to be able to simply get `example`'s score. I tried this: `var player = Players.findOne(Session.get(name:"example")); console.log(player.score);`

But it's obviously wrong. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var player = Players.findOne({name: "example"});
console.log(player.score);
```